# Window loading and Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am creating a website that relies on Firebase Authentication and uses Google Auth.
After the user logs in on a separate page, my website redirects the user to the "main page" where the window loads based on the user that is logged in.

However, if I check if a logged-in user exists at "window.onload," it is always false.
Instead, if I run an async function, and then check for a logged-in user after a ".then", I get true back.

This leads me to hypothesize that "window.onload" fires quicker than the page can recognize the logged-in user.

How do I fix this problem and make sure that the logged-in user loads before I call on my async function?
I am pretty sure firebase.auth() itself is async, but for some reason .then does not seem to work with it.

```
<script>

  window.onload = loadPage();
  
  function loadPage()
  {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(user)
      console.log("userFound before async"); //Does NOT console log

    asyncFunction().then(function()
    {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      if(user)
        console.log("userFound after async"); //Does console log
    })
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something with the currently signed in user, you should use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to register a callback that gets invoked when the user object is first known.  It won't be available when the page initially loads, as you have described in your question.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```

Depending on the completion of other async functions is not advisable - use the observer to know for sure.  It will be invoked whenever it is first known for sure if a user is signed in or not, and again with each change in sign-in state.

Comment: I don't want to call my function as soon as the user logs in. Instead, I would like to only call my function when the "main page" is loaded. There could potentially be a wait time in between the AuthStateChange and the "main page" loading.

Comment: You will have to use the auth state observer to find out **when the user object is first available**.  It's not just for detecting initial sign-in.  As I said in the answer, the user object is simply not available when the page first loads.

Comment: Actually, one more question. On the loading of my "main page," would there be a way to detect if a user is NOT logged in?. I am assuming that onAuthStateChanged would not be called if there is no logged-in user.

Comment: As I said in my answer " It will be invoked whenever it is first known for sure if a user is signed in **or not**". So you will get a callback if not.